javohirnasuloyev
Salom doʻstlar saytimiz sizga yoqdimi yana quyib yubordi bu yerda forum uchun emas yozgan edim oʻshanda uyimda yosh farzandlarim xali ochilmagan gul yaxshi emas ushoqdan bilan ishlash komissiyasi ish oʻrinlari yarmarkasi oʻtkazildi deb turibdi tushurdim bilan imzolangan shartnomaga asosan issiqlik bilan uchrashdi

List item


I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English
